# Trying to save API values into variables gives errors

Tags: python, json, api, flask

So I am trying to save sellprice and buyprice from items in an API. The API consists of 190+ products, and it has a "sell_summary" and a "buy_summary", inside every "sell_summary" and "buy_summary" there is a "pricePerUnit", and that is what I am trying to access, to save into a variable. The values are float, and I have this to access them and save them in variables (productNames is a array with all product names):

```
for x in productNames:
        sell_Price = f["products"][x]["sell_summary"]
```

This doesn't work as it gives me:

```
{'amount': 62, 'pricePerUnit': 1280.2, 'orders': 1}
```

And I am only interested in "pricePerUnit", I also tried to have a ["pricePerUnit] after "sell_summary", but that gives me error *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*. I then tried to add a [0] in between, but that gave me error *IndexError: list index out of range*.

I tried to attack this using arrays instead, and append the values like this:

```
sell_Price = []
    for x in productNames:
        sell_Price.append(f["products"][x]["sell_summary"][:1])
```

(obs: I have to do [:1] as the API can consist of multiple "sections" with pricePerUnit, can be seen in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/XwW4aQVR | only the top "pricePerUnit is interesting as that is latest updated).

But it gave me the same issue with displaying "amount", "pricePerUnit" and "orders". Tried doing [0]["pricePerUnit], but got same errors as before!

```
[0]["pricePerUnit"] = IndexError: list index out of range
[sell_summary][pricePerUnit] = TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I need to save these "pricePerUnit" values to run it through a script I have, that is supposed to calculate (depending on user input) how much they can buy of each product, and how much they can make by buying then selling it!

API link:
https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2

Comment: the problem is that some of the items have an empty list in ["sell_summary" ]

Comment: yes, I know there is one item in the API that has no information, "ENCHANTED_CARROT_ON_A_STICK", they haven't removed that item, even though they have an updated one. "ENCHANTED_CARROT_STICK". Could be the issue, how do I get around it?

Comment: why dont you use the ["quick_status"] endpoit?

Comment: the "quick_status" shows incorrect buy & sell prices, some of them are correct, but items such as "SUPER_COMPACTOR_3000" has a sellprice (in priceperunit) of "497131.9", and in the quick_status it has a sellprice of "488648.9", about 10k difference. I had that before, but later realized that it was incorrect! sell_summary & buy_summary has the correct prices @BendikKnapstad

Comment: I have one way of grabbing the values on another page at this website, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get those values inside of variables, I use this on another page: https://pastebin.com/LHE2jk47 @BendikKnapstad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=73ac0a44-4c41-4933-a9ee-b4095be2b6d2').json()
res = [product['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit'] for product in data['products'].values() if product['sell_summary']]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[4.6, 13.3, 3.1, 66.7, 5.2, 652.6, 1039.6, 2638.9, 105560.6, 9641.0, 1130.5, 2428.0, 345.3, 838.4, 4.3, 476128.5, 4000.6, 3.8, 2005.7, 3.4, 1579.8, 8530.1, 3.9, 2510.4, 932.3, 1903.2, 15.0, 16.6, 23000.3, 7.3, 4422.7, 4.9, 26.7, 10.6, 2356.7, 3.5, 3550.5, 927.4, 22144.9, 11.0, 10.3, 1.7, 3.8, 29.4, 3.0, 595.5, 3.9, 84493.3, 19.1, 1.9, 1266.9, 62904.3, 2226.3, 111750.6, 1753.7, 881.9, 15275.3, 5.9, 667.2, 1.4, 1242.4, 8.7, 8.2, 511.2, 99.3, 785.8, 0.5, 8822.6, 7003.0, 38.2, 13.6, 225.7, 190.7, 1086.1, 1479.1, 236269.6, 1914.4, 63817.0, 207238.8, 1067.1, 421.3, 79499.2, 1.9, 2.8, 81384.8, 360458.7, 13.1, 386.3, 176250.8, 47973.2, 9.1, 17.6, 8.6, 21.1, 1339.3, 98003.3, 2.1, 0.7, 195.8, 22.7, 669.0, 14586.9, 3165.9, 1805.2, 640.1, 47433.5, 5.4, 25891.6, 6.0, 5.4, 591.9, 19435.8, 213667.3, 141335.7, 252100.5, 49.0, 5.0, 20.5, 6776.4, 194.2, 9103.6, 127661.0, 189429.9, 1380.1, 2651.8, 5.7, 152892.4, 473.1, 12.6, 10.4, 35312.0, 95945.5, 1873.9, 497131.4, 232073.2, 1106.2, 6700.7, 5960.9, 369.5, 1689.1, 205200.0, 236353.8, 5.7, 3580.4, 102838.4, 491.9, 4.9, 2639.7, 5108.3, 23.3, 275.1, 2.9, 19293.3, 3704.1, 1100.0, 9.7, 1571.7, 7.8, 175352.9, 391.6, 292445.9, 12.8, 4521.1, 18.6, 24818.1, 6.9, 4498.7, 5.7, 7.4, 37421.6, 642.8, 171720.1, 471.9, 1014.4, 13.9, 3070.3, 14.0, 16.7, 9.8, 785.3, 633.6, 8.1, 718454.0, 22.0, 1270.5, 164062.4, 16.8, 232260.1, 550.2, 57.8, 1750.4, 2800.7, 541161.8, 9.6, 100743.6, 6004.7, 1253.1]
```

Comment: thank you! I might have solved the issue, but this might be a better way of doing it. Does the sell price get stored in "res"?

Comment: yeah it store the results in `res`

Comment: I get an issue with this code: *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sell' referenced before assignment*, here is my code: https://pastebin.com/SGZPhesU

Comment: you are getting are because of your code not because of my code. any way the problem is in your code else condition there is no `sell` variable

Comment: I changed "res" with "sell" though? Don't really see how that would change the output.

Comment: Do I have indent errors with that code? I tested your code on a separate file, and it worked fine, even with "sell" as a variable. It is just that it won't return it when I put it in the correct py file.

Comment: it's not that you are using `sell` variable before defining it you are calculating the values of sell in if condition but in else condition `sell` is not defined `return render_template("flipper.html", product_name=product_name, sell=sell, buy=buy)`

Comment: oh okay, yeah I fixed that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i git this for you:

you have to check if the sell_status is empty first:

```py
for item in products:
    if products[item]["sell_summary"]:
        print(f'{item} sells for: {products[item]["sell_summary"][-1]["pricePerUnit"]}')
```

Comment: I will give it a try! I tried to remove the product with no information and it seems to work, if I run into issues I will try this!

Comment: BTW i didnt know if you wanted the last or first entry in the sell_summary list, change [-1] to [0] if you want the first item

Comment: yeah I got mine here to work, only issue is that the "script" I made, to calculate the profit the user will make for each product doesn't seem to be working. I have to try a few more things, if I cant figure it out I guess I have to make a thread about it. Thanks for telling me about that item that didn't have information, that was the issue!